# Position of 'as well as' in a sentence

Tags: grammar

After considering https://www.lexico.com/definition/as_well_as and https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as-well-as, I would say that 'as well as' is most of the time a preposition, very rarely a conjunction (e.g. second to last example in the Oxford dictionary).

Often 'as well as' is used after a noun (the noun which is accompanied by further items stated after 'as well as'). I was wondering if the following four sentences are equally correct and carry the same meaning:

1. My work is taken into account by the company as well as James' and his girlfriend's work.
2. My work is taken into account as well as James' and his girlfriend's work by the company.
3. My work as well as James' and his girlfriend's work is taken into account by the company.
4. My work, as well as James' and his girlfriend's work, is taken into account by the company

I am pretty sure that 3-4 are correct. In 4, 'as well as' is just additional information that could be put in parentheses. I am not that sure about 1-2. As regards 1, I think the reader understands that 'as well as' does not produce further items for 'company' since 'work' cannot accompany 'company'. I would also be keen to know if your opinion would change if I leave 'by the company' out and 1-2 would become:

5. My work is taken into account as well as James and his girlfriend's work.

Comment: The inclusion of “by the company” is irrelevant. But the second “work” should be omitted, which requires some restructuring.

“My work, **as well as/and that of** James and his girlfriend, is taken into account by the company.”

Comment: Ok, thank you! Apart from mentioning "work" twice, would all my sentences be grammatical?

Comment: Well, you have used "James and her girlfriend when James is male, so that makes it ungrammatical unless "her" refers to some unmentioned woman. Furthermore, it is not merely a question of being "grammatically correct" but it is mainly about being idiomatic.I don't think any of the sentences are really idiomatic - they all sound somewhat awkward. "as well as James' and her girlfriend's" is a free modifier - it modifies the whole of "My work is taken into account by the company." Free modifiers are adverbial and the position of adverbs is quite flexible.

Comment: Yes, „her“ is confusing so I changed that. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Unless you have many Jameses, you should write *James's* as a singular possessive with two syllables.